# Probability of second ball drawn not knowing the first with no replacement

Tags: statistics

I have 50 balls in a bag, 34 green and 16 blue. First person draws a ball but does not show it to me. Then I get to draw what are my chance of drawing a blue ball? This must be conditional probability but I am not sure.

Comment: If you really want to do it the hard way, do this. The probability first drew a green is $34/50$, and then the probability of blue on second is $16/49$. So probability of green first then blue is $(34/50)(16/49)$. A similar calculation can be made for blue then blue. We get that the probability of blue on second is $(34/50)(16/49)+(16/50)(15/49)$. This simplifies to $16/50$, exactly what one gets with no work from Ross Millikan's conceptual argument. The probability the seventh ball is blue is also $16/50$. That would be hideous with a cases approach.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't know what the other person drew, pretend you draw first.  The odds are the same.  Imagine the balls put in order-you get the second one.

Answer (score 1):

I drew a sketch for you: http://sketchtoy.com/61619368

The probability of getting a blue is therefore:

$$P(\text{Blue on 2nd})=\left(\frac{34}{50}\right)\left(\frac{16}{49}\right)+\left(\frac{16}{50}\right)\left(\frac{15}{49}\right)=\frac{8}{25}=32\%$$

Comment: Thanks I liked the picture. All the answers were were good but sketch put this one over the top